# Uniform continuity proof Banach spaces Linear transformations

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces

> **Proposition:** Let $A\in Hom(X,Y)$(Hom(X,Y) is the vector space of linear apllications from $X$ to $Y$).
> Let $||A||=\sup_{x\subset X:||x||\leqslant 1} ||Ax||=\sup_{x\subset X,||x||= 1} ||Ax||=\inf\{M\in\mathbb{R}_+:||Ax||\leqslant M||x||\forall x\in X\}$.
>
> Prove $A$\in $L(X,Y)$($L(X,Y)$continuous linear map) is uniformly continuous.

**Proof**

If $x\neq y$,

$||Ax-Ay||=||A(x-y)||=A(||x-y||\frac{x-y}{||x-y||})=||x-y||A(||x-y||\frac{x-y}{||x-y||})\leqslant ||A||||x-y|| $

which implies $A$ to be uniformly continuous on every point.

**Questions:**

**1)** Norm: I am not understanding the norm used because of the fact it demands $||x||=1$. Why is that? How can $\sup_{x\subset X:||x||\leqslant 1} ||Ax||=\sup_{x\subset X,||x||}$ be equal? In the first $||x||\leqslant 1$ and in the second $||x||=1$.

**2)** Given $A(||x-y||\frac{x-y}{||x-y||})=||x-y||A(||x-y||\frac{x-y}{||x-y||})$. How can this be equal if  the second term it is multiplied by $||x-y||$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in your calculation, it should be:
\begin{align}\|Ax-Ay\| &= \|A(x-y)\| \\
&= \left\|A\left(\frac{x-y}{\|x-y\|}\right)\cdot \|x-y\|\right\| \\
&=\|x-y\|\cdot\left\|A\left(\frac{x-y}{\|x-y\|}\right)\right\|\\
&\le\|x-y\|\cdot\|A\|\cdot\left\|\frac{x-y}{\|x-y\|}\right\|\\
&=\|A\|\cdot\left\|\frac{x-y}{\|x-y\|}\cdot \|x-y\|\right\|\\
&= \|A\|\|x - y\|\end{align}

It would perhaps be easier to follow if you first showed that $\|Av\| \le \|A\|\|v\|$ for all $v \in X$ and then apply it for $v = x - y$.

---

As to why is $$\sup_{\|x\| = 1}\|Ax\| = \sup_{\|x\| \le 1}\|Ax\|$$
first notice that obviously 
$$\sup_{\|x\| = 1}\|Ax\| \le \sup_{\|x\| \le 1}\|Ax\|$$
To show the reverse inequality, let $x \ne 0$ such that $\|x\| \le 1$. Notice that $\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ has norm $1$.

$$\|Ax\| = \underbrace{\|x\|}_{\le 1}\cdot\left\|A\left(\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right)\right\| \le \sup_{\|y\| = 1}\|Ay\|$$

Thus we have:
$$\sup_{\|x\| = 1}\|Ax\| \ge \sup_{\|x\| \le 1}\|Ax\|$$

Don't let it confuse you, taking the supremum over a strictly larger set does not necessarily have to yield a strictly greater supremum:

$$\sup_{x \in [0,1]} x^2= \sup_{x \in [-1,1]} x^2 = 1$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer it has been very helpful. As you stated the supreme over a subset of a larger interval is the same. Why does the author require $||x||=1$ instead of $||Ax||=\sup ||Ax||$?

Comment: @PedroGomes You mean why isn't it defined as $$\|A\| = \sup_{x \in X} \|Ax\|$$
It's because the set $\{\|Ax\| : x \in X\}$ is unbounded when $A \ne 0$. Take $x \in X$ with $Ax \ne 0$. Then for $\lambda > 0$ we have:
$$\|A(\lambda x)\| = \|\lambda \cdot Ax\| = \lambda \cdot \underbrace{\|Ax\|}_{\ne 0} \xrightarrow {\lambda \to +\infty} +\infty$$